# What is the expected number of rolls to get 5 different numbers from a 10-face die?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, expected-value, coupon-collector

Suppose we have a 10-face fair die such that the expected number of rolls to get a particular number from $\{1, 2, \ldots, 10\}$ is $10.$ Then, I am wondering how would I go about finding the expected number of rolls needed to get 5 different numbers. Or more generally, the expected number of rolls needed to get n different numbers where $n < 10.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [coupon collector’s problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). The first number takes $1$ roll. Then you have probability $\frac9{10}$ per roll to get a new number, so the next new number takes $\frac{10}9$ rolls, and so on. The expected number of rolls needed to get $n$ different numbers is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{10}{10-k}=\sum_{j=11-n}^{10}\frac{10}j=10\left(H_{10}-H_{10-n}\right)\;,
$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i$ denote the number of rolls needed to get the $i$th new number. Then $X_1=1$, and $X_i-X_{i-1} \sim Geo((10-(i-1))/10)$.
Hence $$E[X_i] = E[X_1 + \sum_{j=2}^i X_{j}-X_{j-1} =\sum_{j=1}^i \frac{10}{10-(i-1)} ]$$